# How to properly define the types when creating a wrapper hook for useQuery

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, typescript-generics, react-query

I am migrating my existing react project to typescript and have some troubles with the useQuery wrappers that are already defined.

For reference, here's a file which I am currently in the process of migrating.

```
import { UseQueryOptions, useQuery } from "react-query";
import { DASHBOARD_APIS } from "../../../../utils/constants";
import { axiosConfig } from "../../../../utils/utils";

const getAlerts = (payload: AlertsPayload): Promise<AlertsResponse> => {
  return axiosConfig
    .post<AlertsResponse>(DASHBOARD_APIS.alertsList, payload)
    .then((response) => response.data);
};

export const useAlertsList = (
  pageName: "dashboard" | "list",
  payload: AlertsPayload,
  options: UseQueryOptions = {}
) => {
  return useQuery(
    ["alerts-list", pageName, payload],
    () => getAlerts(payload),
    options
  );
};
```

As you can see, I have the actual axios call in a separate function which I am then passing as the query function in the useQuery hook which is wrapped in the `useAlertsList` hook.

Then in my component, I am using this hook as follows:

```
const { dataUpdatedAt, isLoading, isFetching, data } = useAlertsList(
  "dashboard",
  { page: 0, size: 10 },
  { refetchInterval: 60000 }
);
```

**The problem:** the code doesn't compile and throws an error: **'data' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046)**

---

I have tried using the `useQuery` hook directly in my component like below:

```
const { dataUpdatedAt, isLoading, isFetching, data, error } = useQuery(
  ["alerts-list"],
  () => getAlerts({ page: 0, size: 10 }),
  { refetchInterval: 30000 }
);
```

**!!THIS PATTERN WORKS PROPERLY!!**

**`BUT`** it is not preferred in my use case since that particular endpoint is to be used in multiple places across the application, and it is much more friendly to create a wrapper and use that instead. Also, it is not preferred, since the codebase is huge, and changing the pattern across it is a prohibitively huge effort.

---

*Relevant Information*:

- React version: **17.0.2**
- React Query version: **3.19.0**
- Typescript version: **4.5.2**
- **AlertsPayload** & **AlertsResponse** are types declared in a `types.d.ts` file at the module level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `UseQueryOptions` takes in 4 generics, but you are not supplying them,  so they'll infer to the default values.

There are two problems with allowing all options to be passed to `useQuery`:

1. You are creating an abstraction that is very wide. Allowing consumers of your custom hook to pass in all options of useQuery on each and every call-side is not particularly helpful.
2. It's very hard to type. You would need to specify 4 generics, which is very similar to what react-query does internally.

The recommendation is to not allow passing in all options. I understand that this works well in JS, but it doesn't translate easily to TS.

Start without options and see what you need, then pass those values in as you need them. Mostly, it's gonna be just things like `enabled` or `refetchInterval`, which are easy to type.

---

with the upcoming version 5 (currently in beta), you can also create abstractions in the form of `queryOptions` object, and then pass those directly to `useQuery` in your components, without writing a custom hook at all:

```
const alertsListOptions = (
  pageName: "dashboard" | "list",
  payload: AlertsPayload
) => {
  return queryOptions({
      queryKey: ["alerts-list", pageName, payload],
      queryFn: () => getAlerts(payload)
    }
  )
}
```

usage would then just be, in your components:

```
useQuery(alertsListOptions('dashboard', payload))

// or:
useQuery({
  ...alertsListOptions('dashboard', payload),
  enabled: someCondition
})

// or:
useQuery({
  ...alertsListOptions('dashboard', payload),
  select: someTransformation
})
```

all types will be inferred for you, so call-sides have the option to pass whatever options they want, without you having to write those types. But you can't easily do it with custom hooks.

Here's a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVQM4FMCKBXdUCeA8mDMBAHaoA0c2GOe%20NAjrgcaRanAL5wBmUCCDgAiAAIwAhpWkBjANYB6KOilyYAWlaNRAbjhKlcGPjDpUALjgAjdNICwAKFCRYcAFRwp3OdHQCQiIA5JIyqPLKOgSafqrBhsam5la29lLOrtDwUgAeZNyCwnDBeQXBzs7JAQCCADZ4MKgAShaQlAEAvIjOcHDAACbW5NggdlDOPJVO1XD1jagAClL4dRBSA3DdCL39Q3AjY3iT036ycADm9vOw3N0AFGAraxvWN03Lq%20ubAD4H2HU6gBKayLILADAAHneLTaXHQAD4tkidk4%20qoYNgoORvPkIKgAHRXGDQhq3VqodoYBH3YJKKRgYDBIG7PoEmAAC3Q5Hu91UlPhQORcH5VPQBIGUmkQL0k1lTmcZwi3jJTQAMhCYBwyJQtnB7rsnlcAHJSEDoayiSWoDk2dZQAaiOB-UR1TWiKiG57fN6qpbejbO-6A5xCzpI6JEEg61D3VF9BNwSMAaXQ%20GsAG1RFI-Zo3REPXAjehTeaaE8vhsALqetGJpNsfAAMXI1nuYaRxJhjwDAxZdb6Uzr-ecdCwjfuOYWGoi2q4tOttvtA2CNBGgKB-bHDAIcd2BIPU9uM610fnwUXdqkDtXweBtb6ESnABVQBa4ABWAAMP9rPBHThKvAkZ6tuE7xnAB4Eke6qanOlALj4S7Xiua4AveuwYA0GhtpK0rCgAyjAUDAOQFz3HhUj9v%20QA)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way about it -

```ts
export const useAlertsList = (
  pageName: "dashboard" | "list",
  payload: AlertsPayload,
  options: UseQueryOptions = {}
) => {
  return useQuery<AlertsResponse>(
    ["alerts-list", pageName, payload],
    () => getAlerts(payload),
    options
  );
};
```